# c++ error C2664 cannot convert argument 1

Tags: c++

I'm creating a binary tree and I'm trying to implement a function for creating that tree. So that is the code for every member of the tree

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node()
    {
        data = NULL;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};
```

The "BinaryTree" class have only one member called "root" whose type is Node and my function for creating the tree is:

```
void CreateTree(istream &in)
{
    char help;
    int data;
    in >> help;
    while (help == 'y')
    {
        in >> data;
        addLeaf(root, data);
        in >> help;
    }
}
```

and the addLeaf function is:

```
void addLeaf(Node<T>* &nod, int data)
{
    if (nod == NULL)
    {
        nod = new Node<T>();
        nod->data = data;
    }
    else if (data < nod.data) addLeaf(nod->left, data);
    else addLeaf(nod->right, data);
}
```

The result is:

> error C2664: 'void BinaryTree::addLeaf(Node *&,int)' : cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'Node' to 'Node *&'

What should I do?

Comment: The type of `root` is `Node` or `Node*` ?

Comment: The compiler says exactly what is wrong. `root` is a `Node` but `addLeaf` expects a `Node*&`.